# resize 3D image with 5D tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-resizing

I am using 3D convolution for my network. In a node of my network I need to resize my image from `[5,50,50,10,256]` to `[5,100,100,10,256]`. I just want to resize axis 1 and axis 2 of my image.

I tried to use [tf.image.resize_images](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images), but it seems it is only working on 3D or4D tensors.

Any suggestion what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No problem, we can still use tf.image.resize_images.  What we need to do is send the data to **tf.image.resize_images** in the shape that it needs which is a tensor (4D).

```
# First reorder your dimensions to place them where tf.image.resize_images needs them
transposed = tf.transpose( yourData, [0,3,1,2,4] )

# it is now [5,10,50,50,256]
# but we need it to be 4 dimensions, not 5
reshaped = tf.reshape( transposed, [5*10,50,50,256] )

# and finally we use tf.image.resize_images
new_size = tf.constant( [ 100 , 100 ] )
resized = tf.image.resize_images( reshaped , new_size )

# your data is now [5*10,100,100,256]
undo_reshape = tf.reshape( resized, [5,10,100,100,256] )

# it is now [5,10,100,100,256] so lastly we need to reorder it
undo_transpose = tf.transpose( undo_reshape, [0,2,3,1,4] )

# your output is now [5,100,100,10,256]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was so smarty. May I ask why you are transposing the tensor at the first place? Isn't it better first we reshape a [5,50,50,10,256] tensor to [5,50,50,10*256] tensor and after resizing it to [5,100,100,10*256] then reshape it to [5,100,100,10,256]? So, we can avoid extra transposing.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is OK. However, here is another way to achieve this with the built-in method.

```
a  = tf.ones(shape=(5, 50, 50, 10, 256))
tf.keras.backend.resize_volumes(
    a, 
    depth_factor=2, 
    height_factor=2, 
    width_factor=1, 
    data_format="channels_last"
).shape
TensorShape([5, 100, 100, 10, 256])
```

But not that, It may not work to downsample the volumetric data. Because the factor need to be integer. ([Check](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-to-resize-5d-samples-in-keras/8343?u=innat)).